# Randomly split a data frame into halves with conditions being spread out equally across the two halves and within subjects

Tags: r, split, r-caret

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
1   sbj_no  time    condition   
2   100 499.19  cond_A  
3   100 495.11  cond_B  
4   100 380.31  cond_B  
5   100 445.42  cond_A  
6   100 443.95  cond_A
```

More details:

```
my_data <-
  structure(list(
    sbj_no = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
                       .Label = c("100",  "101", "102", "103", "104", "105", 
                                  "106", "107", "108", "109",  "110", "111", "112", 
                                  "113", "114", "115", "116", "117", "118",  "119", 
                                  "120", "121", "122", "123", "124", "125", "126", 
                                  "127",  "128", "129", "130", "131", "132", "133", 
                                  "134", "135", "137",  "138", "139", "140", "141", 
                                  "142", "143", "144", "145", "146",  "147", "148", 
                                  "149", "150", "151", "152", "153", "154", "155",  
                                  "156", "157", "158", "159", "160", "161", "162", 
                                  "164", "165",  "166", "167", "168", "169", "170", 
                                  "171", "172", "173", "174",  "175", "176", "177", "178"), 
                       class = "factor"), 
    time = c(411.3069,  499.197399999957, 495.112099999915, 
             380.319500000041, 445.421600000145,  443.956799999796), 
    condition = c("cond_B", "cond_A", "cond_B", "cond_B", "cond_A", "cond_A")),
    row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Plan:
I want to randomly split the data into two halves balanced on subject (divide up trials per subject across the two halves evenly) AND I also need to do this balanced on condition so that each subject has a approixmately equal amount of cond_A and cond_B in each half.

I have tried various things. I got hopeful when I stumbeled across createDataPartition, so I tried:

```
partition <- caret::createDataPartition(my_data$sbj_no, p = 0.5, list = FALSE)
```

but I cannot figure out how to get the data split balanced on condition within subjects as well.

Any help would be very much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the initial_split function from tidymodels, although its going to work similarly.

```
library(tidymodels)

df_split <- initial_split(df, prop = 0.5, strata = sbj_no)

first_half <- training(df_split)
second_half <- testing(df_split)
```